# Stop HTML5 audio with Javascript (Jquery?) + Zurb Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-audio

Here's my goal: To have autoplay audio stopped when a Zurb Modal window disappears.

I'm new with doing this stuff, especially javascript!

I have a Zurb Modal window functioning as a splash screen that pops up on page load. I have HTML5 audio in the window that autoplays (it was a request - I don't like autoplay!). The window disappears when the background is clicked, but the audio continues to play. I don't know how to get the audio to stop! If anyone has an idea, I'd really appreciate hearing about it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">  

    <audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="audio/splash-loop-01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="audio/splash-loop-01.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
<div class="close-reveal-modal">CLOSE ME</div>​<!-- USE THIS TO CLOSE WINDOW -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#myModal').reveal();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have autoplaying audio? More often than not, visitors experience autoplaying audio as annoying...

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, it is a request - part of the contract. I hate it too.

Comment: Oh, I read over that, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){

    audioPlayer.pause();
    audioPlayer.src = '';
    audioPlayer.load();

    });

});
```

Comment: I haven't got this to work yet. Do I put anything in the audioPlayer.src? - and I hope I entered the code correctly:
$(document).ready(function (){

     $('#myModal').reveal();
     
     
     $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){

    audioPlayer.pause();
    audioPlayer.src = '';
    audioPlayer.load();

    });

});

Answer (score 0):

To pause the audio, place this in your `document.ready`:

```
$('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
    var myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    if(myAudio != undefined){
        myAudio.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: @cerbus... It didn't work, but maybe I've written it incorrectly: 
   $(document).ready(function (){
     
     $('#myModal').reveal();
     
     
     $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
    var myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    if(myAudio != undefined){
        myAudio.pause();
    }
}
     
     
     
});